# Jcheckbox always returnig false in Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am using Java and Swing, all I want to de is to test if the Jcheckbox is selected and if so adding its text to a list of Strings, the problem is that the **isSelected** fuction is always returning False even if the checkbox is selected.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
List<JCheckBox> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
List<String> infos = new ArrayList<String>();
```

```
String sql = "select NAME from drugs ";
pre=con.prepareStatement(sql); 
res=pre.executeQuery(); 
while(res.next()){
    checkBoxes.add(new JCheckBox(res.getString("NAME")));
    panel.add(new JCheckBox(res.getString("NAME")));
}; 
for (JCheckBox checkBox : checkBoxes) {
    if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
        infos.add(checkBox.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're asking why a code snippet is not working, something very difficult to do. Best to create a [mre], one that is free of the database code, and that shows the problem for us. Please read the link.

Comment: Is the key code, where you test the state of the check boxes, being called from within a listener such as an ActionListener or listener to some other event? Or is it called on code creation (before the user interacts with the GUI)?

Comment: If you’re reading the state of a JCheckBox that you just created, then yes, it will always be unselected, because [a JCheckBox created with the String-only constructor is always unselected](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html#%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers, as you can see I got the answer below from CausingUnderflowsEverywhere and the point is that the checkbox I add to my checkBoxes data structure and the checkbox I add to the panel are two different check boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in Java runs once through unless you write code in a loop. You're checking if the checkbox is selected instantly after they are created in the panel. The code is checking if your newly added check boxes are selected (which of course no one has clicked them yet) and then finishes. They are never checked again.

The solution will be to move this selection check into an event handler. But before we get there, you have a second error in your code.

```java
while(res.next()){
    checkBoxes.add(new JCheckBox(res.getString("NAME")));
    panel.add(new JCheckBox(res.getString("NAME")));
};
```

The checkbox you add to your checkBoxes data structure and the checkbox you add to the panel are two different check boxes. Each time you use the **new** keyword in Java, you create a **new independent object**. In your case what you really need is to create 1 new checkbox, and put it in the panel, and also store it in your data structure.

The solution:

```java
while(res.next()){
    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(res.getString("NAME"));
    checkBoxes.add(checkBox);
    panel.add(checkBox);
};
```

Now we can continue to **create an event handler**. An event handler will **react** to someone clicking the check box and run the code that checks the state of the check box to apply any changes. An event handler example to suit your needs can be coded as follows:

```java
checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    infos.add(checkBox.getText());
                }
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                    infos.remove(checkBox.getText());
                }
            }
});
```

Now when we join the code with all the fixes we get:

```java
while(res.next()){
    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(res.getString("NAME"));

    checkBoxes.add(checkBox);
    panel.add(checkBox);

    checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    infos.add(checkBox.getText());
                }
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                    infos.remove(checkBox.getText());
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed the code exactly as you wrote above and it is working fine, now I see the point and understand the difference, thank you.